# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - Access violation reading location x

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing a somewhat toy program to get into c++. However I'm having quite a lot of trouble with a segmentation fault at a very specific line in my code. I know that the segmentation fault means I tried to access memort that was not given to my program.
The code is (somewhat) as follows(it's actually too big to just copy paste) :

```
class car {
protected:
   int speed;
   std::string brand;
public:
   car (int s, std::string b):speed(s),brand(b) {
       std::cout << "New car has been created" << endl;
   }
   virtual int is_stopped () {
      if (speed==0) return 1;
      else return 0;
   }
   virtual void speed_up () {
       speed++;
   }
   car* clone () {
      car* tmp(this);
      return tmp;
   }
};
class fast_car : public car {
public:
   fast_car (int s, std::string b):car(s,b) { } 
};
class slow_car : public car {
public:
   slow_car (int s, std::string b):car(s,b) { }
};
class highway {
   int number_of_cars;
   car **first;           //There are derived classes from car hence the                double pointer
public:
   highway (int c, int s, std::string b):number_of_cars(c) {
      first = new car*[c];
      for (int i=0;i<c/2;i++)
          first[i] = new fast_car (s,b);
      for (int i=c/2;i<c;i++)
          first[i] = new slow_car (s,b);
   }
   void speed_up () {
      int pos;
      pos = rand()%number_of_cars;    //give me a random number between 0 and number_of_cars;
      if (pos!=0) pos--;   //We don't want position -1
          first[pos]->speed_up ();
      clone_fast (first[pos], (number_of_cars - pos - 1)); //the second argument is the remaining array "spots" until the end of the array
   }



   void clone_fast (car* cur, int rem) {
      car* tmp;
      for (int i=-;i<=rem;i++) 
         if ((cur+1)->is_stopped ()) {   //Exact line where I get the segmentation fault
            tmp = cur->clone ();
            cur++;
         }
   }
};
```

So there it is. I tried to give you everything I could to recreate the problem. I'll try to solve any further questions.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `cur`? It's not declared or assigned anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Some advices: learn about RAII and forget all you heard about pointers, new and delete. Use standard library containers (std::vector) and smart pointers.

Comment: @kebs cur would be the <current> argument. My bad. I am coming in from java (beginner there as well) and I was wondering how I could use pointers to my advantage but, as it seems, they're just too difficult to handle. In any case I would like to figure out the answer to this problem because I cannot, for the life of me, figure it out.

Comment: Your `clone` function is wrong. All it does is return the `this` pointer. That is not how `clone()` functions are supposed to work. You need to do either a shallow or deep memory copy of the data pointed to by `this`. (that doesn't explain the crash, but that will explain your next SO posting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `car*`s are created by `new`, and aren't necessarily contiguous; they certainly aren't arrays that you can pointer-arithmetic around with. `(car*) + 1` is not the same as `(car**)[i + 1]` (which is more like `(car**) + 1`). You probably want something a bit more like `(*(first + 1))->doThing()`, not `(first[X] + 1)->doThing()`.

Edit: to be a bit more clear, if you can't do `car[X + 1]`, then you can't do `*(car + 1)`. Since the `car`s in `clone_fast()` are object pointers and not arrays, you can't do `car[X + 1]`, thus `(cur + 1)->is_stopped()` is wrong.

Comment: Oh my god this actually worked. I wouldn't have imagined that pointer arithmetics wouldn't work because of the new. Thank you very much. :D

Comment: It's not so much about `new` as it is the things you're handing to `clone_fast()` aren't arrays in the first place, so treating the pointer like they were arrays gives you segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing all pointer crap, and use more modern idioms. You can expand on the code below. However, it is unclear to me why you have two derived classes: they have no specific data neither methods, so why ?

```
class car
{
private:
    int speed;
    std::string brand;

public:
    car (int s, std::string b):speed(s),brand(b)
    {
        std::cout << "New car has been created" << endl;
    }
    bool is_stopped ()
    {
        return speed==0;
    }
    void speed_up ()
    {
        speed++;
    }
};

class fast_car : public car
{
    public:
        fast_car (int s, std::string b):car(s,b) {}
};

class slow_car : public car
{
    public:
        slow_car (int s, std::string b):car(s,b) {}
};

class highway
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<car>> v_cars;
    public:
        highway (int c, int s, std::string b):number_of_cars(c)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<c/2;i++)
                v_cars.push_back( std::make_shared<fast_car>(s,b) );
            for (int i=c/2;i<c;i++)
                v_cars.push_back( std::make_shared<slow_car>(s,b) );
        }

};

int main()
{
    highway h( 50, 20 );
    return 0;
}
```